# List.sum on custom class

Tags: list, scala, types, sum

I have the following code that represents GF2 field:

```
trait GF2 {
  def unary_- = this
  def + (that: GF2): GF2
  def * (that: GF2): GF2

  def / (that: GF2) = that match {
    case Zero => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Div by 0")
    case _ => this
  }
}

object Zero extends GF2 {
  override def toString = "Zero"
  def + (that: GF2) = that
  def * (that: GF2) = this
}

object One extends GF2 {
  override def toString = "One"
  def + (that: GF2) = that match { case One => Zero ; case _ => this }
  def * (that: GF2) = that match { case One => this ; case _ => that }
}
```

And now I'd like to call this function: `List(One, One, Zero, One).sum` such that `GF2._+` would be called for summation, how can I accomplish that? Should `GF2` extend some interface or should I implemet type class technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a Numeric[GF2] implicit:

```
trait GF2IsNumeric extends Numeric[GF2] {
  def plus(x: GF2, y: GF2): GF2 = x + y
  def minus(x: GF2, y: GF2): GF2 = x + (-y)
  def times(x: GF2, y: GF2): GF2 = x * y
  def negate(x: GF2): GF2 = -x
  def fromInt(x: Int): GF2 = ???
  def toInt(x: GF2): Int = ???
  def toLong(x: GF2): Long = ???
  def toFloat(x: GF2): Float = ???
  def toDouble(x: GF2): Double = ???
  override def zero = Zero
  override def one = One
}

trait GF2Ordering extends scala.math.Ordering[GF2] {
  override def compare(a: GF2, b: GF2) = if (a == b) 0 else if (b == One) 1 else -1
}

implicit object GF2IsNumeric extends GF2IsNumeric with GF2Ordering
```

Then you can do:

```
println(List(One, One, Zero, One).sum)
// One
```

Comment: So this is an example of type class implementation, right?

Comment: But if I do `println(List(One, One, One).sum)` it fails to find implicit value because it's `List[One.type]` now. Should I use `List[GF2](One)` in such cases or is there a better way?

Comment: @Anton.  Personally, I would set it up where GF2 is a class (really, a **value class** `extends AnyVal`) and just have `val Zero = new GF2(0)`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the signature of `sum`:

```
def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B
```

I was about to suggest that you make `GF2` a member of `Numeric` typeclass by providing and implicit value of type `Numeric[GF2]`, but then I looked at the definition of `Numeric` and realized that it contains a ton of operations completely irrelevant to summation that you would have to implement.

I don't like this, I think `sum` method should require some more abstract typeclass (a monoid, perhaps?).

So, I think your best option (unless you want to implement entire `Numeric` instance) is to use either `reduce` (will work only with non-empty lists) or `fold`:

```
yourList.reduce(_ + _)
yourList.fold(Zero)(_ + _)
```

Comment: That's sure an option but I'm kinda learning scala while programming this so I really want to know how these things can be done the `sum` way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a version of `Numeric` for your trait in order for it to work. See [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) for the full definition you'll need to create.

```
 object InScope{
   implicit object GF2Numeric extends Numeric[GF2]{
     //..your implementation here
   }
 }
```

The full signature of `sum` on a `List` is actually:

```
 def sum(implicit num: Numeric[A])
```

Where by the `A` is the type of the `List[A]`.

Comment: The full signature is actually `def sum[B <: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B`