# How to extend a Scala list to enable slicing not by explicit position but by given predicate/condition

Tags: list, scala, collections, slice

For

```
trait Item
case class TypeA(i: Int) extends Item
case class TypeB(i: Int) extends Item
```

consider a Scala list of items such as

```
val myList = List(TypeA(1), TypeB(11), TypeB(12), 
                  TypeA(2), TypeB(21), 
                  TypeA(3), TypeB(31))
```

The goal is to define a new `slice` method that can be applied onto `myList` and which takes a predicate or condition as argument; for instance

```
myList.slice { x => x.isInstanceOf[TypeA] }
```

would deliver

```
List(List(TypeA(1), TypeB(11), TypeB(12)), 
     List(TypeA(2), TypeB(21)), 
     List(TypeA(3), TypeB(31)))
```

In this example, an identical result would be achieved by

```
myList.slice { case TypeA(x) => x < 10 }
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: oh. do you mean that the predicate defines "things that begin a new sub-list"?

Comment: @Rob Starling that's right, the predicate defines the lower bound of each sub-list.

Comment: what are you looking for in the case that the input doesn't contain (or doesn't begin with) elements that satisfy the predicate?

Comment: @Rob Starling `List span` proves a simpler, well-defined case, as depicted by @Kevin Wright; a `multiSpan` method is quested here, ideally callable from a list instance more than as a separate method with list and predicate as arguments.

Comment: @user3189923 - Okay, I showed how to do that as well in my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List` already has a `slice` method - it takes a subset of elements between a start and end index.  What you're looking for is repeated application of the `span` method:

```
def span(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): (List[A], List[A])
```

Which is documented as:

> Splits this list into a prefix/suffix pair according to a predicate.
>
> *Note: c span p is equivalent to (but possibly more efficient than) (c takeWhile p, c dropWhile p), provided the evaluation of the predicate p does not cause any side-effects.*
>
> **returns:** a pair consisting of the longest prefix of this list whose elements all satisfy p, and the rest of this list.

You can get what you need by repeatedly using this method with an inverse predicate, and an extra bit of logic to ensure that none of the returned Lists are empty.

```
import annotation.tailrec

def multiSpan[A](xs: List[A])(splitOn: (A) => Boolean): List[List[A]] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(xs: List[A], acc: List[List[A]]) : List[List[A]] = xs match {
    case Nil => acc

    case x :: Nil => List(x) :: acc

    case h :: t =>
      val (pre,post) = t.span(!splitOn(_))
      loop(post, (h :: pre) :: acc)
  }
  loop(xs, Nil).reverse
}
```

**UPDATE**

As requested in comments on the original post, here's a version that enriches list instead of being a standalone method:

```
implicit class AddMultispanToList[A](val list: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def multiSpan(splitOn: (A) => Boolean): List[List[A]] = {
    @tailrec
    def loop(xs: List[A], acc: List[List[A]]) : List[List[A]] = xs match {
      case Nil => acc

      case x :: Nil => List(x) :: acc

      case h :: t =>
        val (pre,post) = t.span(!splitOn(_))
        loop(post, (h :: pre) :: acc)
    }
    loop(list, Nil).reverse
  }
}
```

Use as:

```
myList.multiSpan(_.isInstanceOf[TypeA])
```

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time I've had to tackle this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you use partition method from the standard API?

example:

```
scala> val l = List(3,5,4,6)
l: List[Int] = List(3, 5, 4, 6)

scala> 

scala> val (odd,even) = l.partition(_ %2 ==1)
odd: List[Int] = List(3, 5)
even: List[Int] = List(4, 6)
```

For your example:

```
scala> val (typeA,typeB) = myList.partition(_.isInstanceOf[TypeA])
typeA: List[Product with Serializable with Item] = List(TypeA(1), TypeA(2), TypeA(3))
typeB: List[Product with Serializable with Item] = List(TypeB(11), TypeB(12), TypeB(21), TypeB(31))
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the idea; partition would bisect the initial list into two; in this case we would need multiple sublists, the lower bound of each is defined by a condition...

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get more than two sublists? Then you would probably have to write a macro for that, or use map + match + groupBy

Comment: Wish a similar answer as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/21787505/3189923 where class `List` gets equipped with a `sum` method for a specialised set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you looking for `filter`, which works (almost) without any tweaks for your examples?

```
$ sbt console
scala> trait Item
scala> case class TypeA(i: Int) extends Item
scala> case class TypeB(i: Int) extends Item
scala> val myList = List(TypeA(1), TypeB(11), TypeB(12), 
                         TypeA(2), TypeB(21), 
                         TypeA(3), TypeB(31))
myList: List[Product with Serializable with Item] = List(TypeA(1), TypeB(11), TypeB(12), TypeA(2), TypeB(21), TypeA(3), TypeB(31))
```

your first works unaltered:

```
scala> myList.filter { x => x.isInstanceOf[TypeA] }
res0: List[Product with Serializable with Item] = List(TypeA(1), TypeA(2), TypeA(3))
```

your second requires a default case:

```
scala> myList.filter { case TypeA(x) => x < 10; case _ => false }
res2: List[Product with Serializable with Item] = List(TypeA(1(3))
```

See also `collect`, which takes a partial function instead of a boolean predicate:

```
scala> myList.collect { case z @ TypeA(x) if x < 10 => z }
res3: List[TypeA] = List(TypeA(1), TypeA(2), TypeA(3))
```

and can transform as well:

```
scala> myList.collect { case TypeA(x) if x < 10 => x }
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```