# Group list elements by string-int* pattern

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a list:

```
List[Any]("foo", 1, 2, "bar", 3, 4, 5)
```

I would like to group it's elements this way:

```
Map("foo" -> List(1,2), "bar" -> List(3,4,5))
```

I can only imagine a solution in an imperative style with mutable lists and vars, but what is the proper way of solving this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward.

If the list has elements, take all ints from the `tail` and drop the rest, which is stored in `rest`. That is what `span` does. Then map the `head` to the `ints` and recursivly do it for the `rest`.

```
def f(a: List[Any]): Map[String, List[Int]] = a match {
  case Nil => Map.empty
  case head :: tail => {
    val (ints, rest) = tail.span(_.isInstanceOf[Int])
    f(rest) + (head.asInstanceOf[String] -> ints.map(_.asInstanceOf[Int]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `multiSpan` as defined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803339/3189923 ; then for

```
val a = List[Any]("foo", 1, 2, "bar", 3, 4, 5)
```

we have that

```
val b = a.multiSpan(_.isInstanceOf[String])
b: List[List[Any]] = List(List(foo, 1, 2), List(bar, 3, 4, 5))
```

and so

```
b.map { l => (l.head, l.tail) }.toMap
res: Map(foo -> List(1, 2), bar -> List(3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive way:

```
@tailrec
def toMap(list:List[Any], acc:Map[String,List[Int]] = Map()):Map[String,List[Int]] = list match {
  case Nil => acc
  case List(key:String, _*) => {
    val values = list.drop(1).takeWhile(_.isInstanceOf[Int]).map {case i:Int => i}
    toMap(list.drop(1+values.size), acc + (key -> values))
  }
}
```

Seems to work correctly:

```
scala> toMap(list)
res0: Map[String,List[Any]] = Map(foo -> List(1, 2), bar -> List(3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: Our solutions are pretty similar. I would advise you to use `span` though, so you can take and drop at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
def toMap(seq: Seq[Any]) = {
    val (result, _) = seq.foldRight((Map.empty[String, Seq[Int]], "")) {
      (el, acc) =>
        val (map, str) = acc
        el match {
          case s: String =>
            (map, s)
          case number: Int =>
            val el = map.getOrElse(str, Seq[Int]())
            (map + (str -> (number +: el)), str)
        }
    }
    result
  }
```

===Test==

```
scala> val list = List[Any]("foo", 1, 2, "bar", 3, 4, 5)
list: List[Any] = List(foo, 1, 2, bar, 3, 4, 5)

scala> toMap(list)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[Int]] = Map(foo -> List(2, 1), bar -> List(5, 4, 3))
```