# split a list of objects into different lists depending on a predicate splittor

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a list like this:

```
val data = List("a","b","","c","d","e","","a","b","c")
```

I want to split it from the elements "":

```
List(List("a","b"),List("c","d","e"),List("a","b","c"))
```

What would be the Scala way?

something like:

```
data.MAGIC(_=="")
```

Comment: Will you always want to drop the elements that match the predicate?

Comment: It's pretty much a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800041/how-to-extend-a-scala-list-to-enable-slicing-not-by-explicit-position-but-by-giv/21803339#21803339

Comment: @Paul if we can not drop the method element it would be okay, because I know it will be always head of the output lists.

Comment: OK, in which case you can use that duplicate question?

Answer (score 3):

Using `span`:

```
def magic[T](l: List[T]): List[List[T]] = {
  @tailrec
  def magicAux[T](l: List[T], r: MutableList[List[T]]): MutableList[List[T]] = {
    val (p, s) = l.span(_ != "")
    s match {
      case Nil => r += p
      case _   => magicAux(s.tail, r += p)
    }
  }
  magicAux(l, new MutableList[List[T]]()).toList
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jean, but I'm searching for some kind of collection way, do you think is there any "nicer" way

Comment: @Omid If by "nicer" you mean something in the standard library, there isn't anything that does this. And if there were, it would be a method that looks something like this.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
scala> Stream.iterate(""::data){ _.tail.dropWhile(_.nonEmpty) }
       .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
       .map{ _.tail.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty) }.toList
res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b), List(c, d, e), List(a, b, c))
```

Or this one:

```
scala> (-1 +: data.zipWithIndex.collect{ case ("", i) => i } :+ data.size)
       .sliding(2).toList
       .map{ case List(h, t) => data.slice(h+1,t) }
res2: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b), List(c, d, e), List(a, b, c))
```

And this one:

```
scala> (data:+"").foldLeft(List[List[String]](), List[String]()){ 
         case((xs, x), v) => if(v.isEmpty) (x.reverse::xs, Nil) else (xs,v::x) 
       }._1.reverse
res3: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b), List(c, d, e), List(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `foldRight`:

```
  val res = ("" :: data).foldRight(List[List[_]](Nil))((x, s) =>
    (x, s) match {
      case ("", Nil :: _) => s
      case ("", _)        => Nil :: s
      case (x, h :: t)    => (x :: h) :: t
    }).tail
```