# Scala: groupBy based on boolean applied to next element

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scalaz

If I had a List that looked like this:

```
List("abdera.apache.org lists:", "commits", "dev", "user",
"accumulo.apache.org lists:", "commits", "dev", "notifications", "user")
```

And I wanted to end with a

```
Map("abdera.apache.org lists:" -> Seq("commits", "dev", "user"), 
"accumulo.apache.org lists:" -> Seq("commits", "dev", "notifications", "user"))
```

How would I do that?

I've been trying `groupBy`, but I'm not sure how to apply a boolean to first get the key (i.e. `string.contains("lists:")`) and then a boolean to the next element to test if it doesn't contain "lists:" and therefore add it as a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the structure of you list is

```
List(key, item, item, item, 
     key, item ..., item, 
     key, item, ...)
```

You can build a map like that with a `foldLeft`:

```
val list = List("abdera.apache.org lists:", "commits", "dev", "user",
  "accumulo.apache.org lists:", "commits", "dev", "notifications", "user")

val map: Map[String, List[String]] =
  list.foldLeft(List.empty[(String, List[String])]) {

    case (acc, curr) if curr.endsWith("lists:") =>
      // identified a list key
      curr -> List.empty[String] :: acc

    case (((headListKey, headList)) :: tail, curr) =>
      // append current string to list of strings of head, until next list key is found
      (headListKey, curr :: headList) :: tail

  }.toMap.mapValues(_.reverse)
```

If the key strings do not always end the same way, you might want to use a regular expression to identify the key strings in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Using `multiSpan` as defined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803339/3189923 , given

```
val xs = List("abdera.apache.org lists:", "commits", "dev", "user",
              "accumulo.apache.org lists:", "commits", "dev",
                                            "notifications", "user")
```

we have that

```
xs.multiSpan(_.contains("lists:"))
```

delivers a list of lists,

```
List(List(abdera.apache.org lists:, commits, dev, user),
     List(accumulo.apache.org lists:, commits, dev, notifications, user))
```

We can thus transform the resulting nested lists into the desired `Map`, for instance as follows,

```
xs.multiSpan(_.contains("lists:")).map( ys => ys.head -> ys.tail ).toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

And again assuming that structure is always as outlined above:

```
val list = List("abdera.apache.org lists:", "commits", "dev", "user",
  "accumulo.apache.org lists:", "commits", "dev", "notifications", "user")

Map(list.grouped(4).map(l => (l.head -> l.tail)).toList : _*)
```

If you insist on getting a `Seq` then you can do `l.tail.toSeq` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the key is "annotated" with a colon and there are an unknown number of items, so my solution will not work.

Comment: This would definitely work if there was always 3 trailing items though!