# Scala: Find max sum of consecutive negative numbers in a List of Double

Tags: scala, list, subset

I have a `List[Double]` with the following values:

```
{-1.2200000000000006, -1.3200000000000003, -1.0099999999999998, 22.22, 11.11, 
-31.310000000000002, -0.9799999999999986,-4, -5, 3, 2, 2.959999999999999}`
```

I was to find the max sum of the consecutive negative numbers.

So from original list to separate consecutive lists of negative and positive

```
{ 
  {-1.2200000000000006, -1.3200000000000003, -1.0099999999999998},
  {22.22, 11.11},
  {-31.310000000000002, -0.9799999999999986,-4, -5},
  {3, 2, 2.959999999999999}
}
```

then remove the positive consecutive numbers

```
{ 
  {-1.2200000000000006, -1.3200000000000003, -1.0099999999999998},
  {-31.310000000000002, -0.9799999999999986,-4, -5}
}
```

then sum

```
{-3.5500000000000007, -41.29}
```

then change to absolute values

```
{3.5500000000000007, 41.29}
```

then find max = 41.29

Comment: Your question is a bit fuzzy. 1 - Do you want to sum consecutive pairs of negative numbers or the sum of all consecutive negative numbers? 2 - The sum of negative numbers is also negative so `32.29` can't be correct. 3 - The maximum negative number is the one closest to zero. Do you want max or min?

Comment: @jwvh I've edited the message to explain it better.  It's the sum of consecutive negative numbers rather than the sum of PAIRS of negative numbers which is what I think the solutions posted are right now.

Comment: You could use `multiSpan` from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800041/how-to-extend-a-scala-list-to-enable-slicing-not-by-explicit-position-but-by-giv/21803339#21803339. Then sum the sublists, take the **minimum**, then the absolute value of that is the answer you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* mean to **sum** all the consecutive negative numbers, and then find the **maximum** sum, this will do it.

```
val nums = List(-1.2200000000000006, -1.3200000000000003, -1.0099999999999998, 
       22.22, 11.11, -31.310000000000002, -0.9799999999999986, 2.959999999999999)

nums.foldLeft(List[Double]()){
  case (l,n) if n < 0 => if (l.isEmpty) List(n) else n + l.head :: l.tail
  case (l, _) => Double.MinValue :: l
}.max
// res0: Double = -3.5500000000000007
```

**update**

OK, a minor change will get you what you're after.

```
nums.foldLeft(List(0.0)){
  case (l,n) if n < 0 => n + l.head :: l.tail
  case (l, _) => 0.0 :: l
}.min.abs // res0: Double = 32.29
```

Note: What you're actually after is the minimum sum. If you want it expressed as a positive number you can get the absolute value after the fact.

Comment: again, thanks but that's not what I'm looking for.  I'll put more detail in the original message.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh appreciate all your help on this.  Yes, that worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foldLeft` for that:

```
    val (max, _) = list.foldLeft((0,0)) { 
      case((max, current), n) if(n >= 0) => (max, 0)
      case((m, current), n) => 
         val sum = current - n
         (sum max m, sum)
     }
```

Comment: thanks but this is giving me the sum of pairs.  I want the sum of consecutive nos.  I've edited the original message to give more detail.

Comment: No, the idea is for it to accumulate the sum as long as the numbers are negative. For example, is `val list  = Seq(1, -1, -2, -3, 2, 3, -1, -5, -10, 4, 5)`, then the result is 16.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`sliding`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sliding(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator[Repr]).

For sums of consecutive pairs of negative numbers:

```
val doubles = List(-1.2200000000000006, -1.3200000000000003, ...)
val result = doubles.sliding(2)
                    .collect { case List(a, b) if a < 0 && b < 0 => List(a, b) }
                    .map(_.sum)
                    .min
                    .abs
```

Comment: thanks but this is giving me the sum of pairs.  I want the sum of consecutive nos.  I've edited the original message to give more detail.