# Scala Numeric-Like for custom Classes

Tags: scala, sum

I've created some Value Classes in Scala 2.10.2 to represent units of electricity, e.g. Voltage, Current, Power, Energy etc. They are only allowed to be combined in particular sensible ways, e.g. you can multiply Voltage by Current, but not Voltage by Energy.

A common use case is working out the total energy over a sequence of energies. For this, I'd like to use

```
val energies : Seq[Energy] = ...
energies.sum()
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Energy]
```

which makes perfect sense.

I could implement Numeric[Energy], but that would require me to define `times( Energy, Energy )`, which I don't want to do, because it's not a valid type. Does anyone have a suggestion of how this can be accomplished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List.sum on custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787505/list-sum-on-custom-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum needs `Numeric[T]` and you cannot allow `Numeric[Energy]` so you cannot use `sum`. Maybe you could introduce your own set of helper functions for operations you often want to do on collections of your types?

Id take a look at squants and see if/how they have solved that problem. (http://www.squants.com)

Comment: It is now noted in their README: e.g., import `squants.mass.MassConversions.MassNumeric`: https://github.com/typelevel/squants#numeric-support